# How do you use hyperlinks with a Node.js web server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send different html files to users, with index.html being a bunch of hyperlinks that a user can click on to see that file, but I get an error that says "cannot GET (that file's name)" whenever I click on a hyperlink.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Here's my index.html:

```
<html>

<a href="/pongClient.html">Pong Game </a>

</html>
```

Comment: where are you storing pongClient.html?

Comment: For usual people use template engines like ejs , handlebars or pub and create a dictionary named "views" and store all their templates in there.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I'm storing pongClient.html in the same folder as my server.js & index.html

Comment: make that folder available from the server using `express.static` on the folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a public static file folder like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Everything you have in your public folder will be accessible at the root of your URL (i.e. `/pongClient.html`)

Comment: hmmmm it gives me the error, "express not defined". Should I use, app.static instead?

Comment: You should split your first require, like this: `var express = require('express'); var app = express();`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to setup the `node` server so that it knows where to get the file from and You can setup a static server in this case. The syntax in express can be found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

> To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the `express.static` built-in middleware function in Express.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname)) //since the index.html and probably pongClient.html are in the current directory based on your code.

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs has nothing to do with hyperlink. But if you want your user to access different page use

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<p><a href="http://localhost:80/pongClient.html">Pong Game</a></p>\n');
});
```

The port number is 80(I am assuming your web server port is 80).Mainly you have to give full URL(accessible ones).